# Java ScheduledExecutorService standard practice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService in a J2EE application to schedule a task every x seconds taken from a config file (picks up data from a database and sends them to a external server).  My code is:

```
try{
    final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
                RsaBaseAction rsa = RsaBaseAction.getInstance();//class that does all the work
                rsa.rsaBaseAction();
            }
          }, 0, timeInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

My question is is there any extra code I should be writing?  Should I write a while loop to make sure thread is completed then do a `service.shutdown()` or does `ScheduledExecutorService` take care of that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call `shutdown` if you wanted the scheduler to stop scheduling the events. You don't need to explicitly do this as if you want it to run for the lifetime of your application. You would use the `shutdown` method if for some reason the scheduling no longer made any sense.

An example. You're writing a CMS that offers integration with google shopping to upload product information. If the user removes their upload information (ie turned it off), you could call shutdown to stop the service doing the synchronization.

Comment: ah got it, thanks.  My thing is supposed to run indefinitely until the app server is stopped.  I was just worried about memory leaks or continuous spawning of threads.

Comment: The scheduler internally has one thread for running your code. That's why the method is called `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`. If you scheduled 10,000 runnables, it would all happen on one thread, albeit slowly.

Answer (score 0):

As the Javadoc on the `shutdown` method clearly states:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>   This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

I.e. previous tasks are going to be finished, no new ones are going to be done, however a previous task may continue past the `shutdown` command if it takes a while.

As for the code you have - I do not see any reason for the try-catch block. Scheduling tasks does not throw any exceptions. It looks like you want to actually try-catch the `rsaBaseAction` instead of the scheduling (if an exception is thrown by the runnable, no more executions are scheduled and the exception is handled by the thread group exception handler)

Comment: i didnt have a try-catch but it seems when there is a exception in the task there is no stack trace print in console, instead it goes into the ScheduledExecutorService own code and it gets hunged there.  Took me a while to figure that one out haha.  I put a catch there to see if it will be caught here instead